# Python - Attribute Error '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I receive an error

```
File.open(classname+'.txt','a')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'
```

while trying to open a file. I need to open the file and write to the file with the scores.

Here is the code

```
if Exists==False:
    File.open(classname+'.txt','a')
    File.write(name+','+surname+','+str(1)+','+str(score)+'/n')

else:
    File=open(classname+'.txt','w')
    linecount=len(filelines)
    for i in range(0,linecount):
        File.write(filelines[i])
```

Comment: The line you say is causing the error does not appear in the code you have posted.

Comment: Give the full error, including the line number, and indicate where it occurs.

Comment: Apologies @Daniel  , I have edited the attribute error, it should be what it is now.

Comment: You need `File = open` instead of `File.open`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
File=open(classname+'.txt','a')
File.write(name+','+surname+','+str(1)+','+str(score)+'/n')
File.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the beginning you declare

```
File=open(classname+'.txt','r+')
```

and then you ask again to open File

```
File.open(classname+'.txt','a')
```

but `File` is already `open(classname+'.txt','r+')`. Just skip `File.open(classname+'.txt','a')` and it should work fine.