# Fail to open "_io.TextIOWrapper" ob

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to open a file using `tkiner.filedialog.askopenfile()` (see the below code).

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
words_file = askopenfile(mode='r', title='Select word list file')
```

following this, a textfile is selected and saved to `words_file`.
I'm now trying to open this with `open(words_file, 'r')` but get the error
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper`

How do I open the `_io.TextIOWrapper` object? I have found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728990/python-attribute-error-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-open) but could not figure out what the problem is in my case.
Could some kindly enlighten me? ;)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`askopenfile` returns an already-open file. If you want the file *name*, call `askopenfilename`.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley), `askopenfile` already returns an open file.

What I had to do to achieve what I wanted was to simply proceed into with `words_file.readline()` straight away.

```
>>> words_file.readline()
'First line'
```